# Showing all reminders in iOS 8 widget

Tags: notifications, reminders, ios, widgets

I love using the Reminders app for my todo list, and a big part of that is that you can just pull down the "Today" menu and see all your current todos, and check off any you've completed.

But now on iOS 8, the Reminders widget only shows 4-5 items and then has a "see all" link that opens the Reminders app. This is a HUGE step down for efficiency for me.

Is there any way to make the Reminders widget show all of your reminders, like it did on iOS 7?